# MSTest Assert.AreEqual fails with string array

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm working up some unit tests and unsure why this particular test is failing.

The test is to assert that a custom view engine looks in the correct place for views.

In my custom view engine is this:

```
AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[]
{
    "~/Areas/{2}/App/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/App/Shared/Views/{0}.cshtml"
};
```

And in my test is this:

```
string[] expected = new[]
{
    "~/Areas/{2}/App/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/App/Shared/Views/{0}.cshtml"
};

CustomRazorViewEngine engine = new CustomRazorViewEngine();

Assert.AreEqual(expected, engine.AreaMasterLocationFormats);
```

The test fails with the message:

```
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<System.String[]>. Actual:<System.String[]>.
```

(s/o's quote format doesn't like the second lt in that...)

I'm unsure why, as when I debug the test all appears well.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your answer (whoever you were), but it was correct...

Comment: For a moment, I wasn't sure `string[]` is actually a `Collection`.

Comment: @haim770 Apparently, seeing as how the test passes now :)  I'll except when my timer's up, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `CollectionAssert` instead:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, engine.AreaMasterLocationFormats);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal.aspx)